# Creating log files on external storage in Android. Is there a correct way to do that?

Tags: android, logging, error-logging

right now I'm creating an app that is tested in release build with added proguard.
As you may imagine, there are some differences between things I write and test, and things that people use. Sometimes I get a bug report saying that something doesn't work. Well... it works for me, right?

So, my idea was to write some kind of LogManager that writes new line to text file on the device. This is my implementation, that essentially works:

```
@Application
public class LogManager {

private static final String TAG = LogManager.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String FOLDER_NAME = "/logs/";
private static final String FILE_NAME = "app_logs.txt";

DateTime dateTime;
DateTimeFormatter parser;
String date;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
File logFile;
Gson gson;

@Inject
public LogManager(Gson gson) {
    parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    this.gson = gson;
    createFile();
}

private void createFile(){
    if(isExternalStorageReadable() && isExternalStorageWritable()){
        try {
            File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+FOLDER_NAME);
            path.mkdirs();
            logFile = new File(path, FILE_NAME);
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void log(Object o){
    log(gson.toJson(o));
}

public void log(String text){
    dateTime = new DateTime();
    date = parser.print(dateTime);

    String log = date + "    " + text;
    try{
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(logFile, true);
        fileOutputStream.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.write(log.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void printLogs(){
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFile));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    L.d(TAG, text.toString());
}

public void deleteLog(){
    L.d(TAG, "Log File deleted: "+logFile.delete());
}

private boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
}

private boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
}
```

So yeah. However I'm not sure how it would behave in ... future use. For example what happens when I try to use it on different treads? I know I will, beacause I'm downloading lots of stuff asynchronously.

So, my question is... is there some "official" way how to handle this? Maybe some kind of logging library? 
Or maybe my code is okay and needs only some tweaks?

EDIT:
Sample usage.

```
...

@Inject
LogManager logManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_userconfig);
    App.getInstance().appComponent.inject(this);

    logStuff();
}

private void logStuff(){
    logManager.log("abc");
    logManager.log("def");

    logManager.printLogs();
}
```

Because I'm using Dagger2 library, LogManager injected in all classes should be the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Official way to do this.

Take a look at this 2 libraries:[Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo) and [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber).

Several issues with your code:

- When loggin to Logcat u should also log to the file but at your code
  u didnt log to logcat, didint wrap it correctly. so at every point
  that you want to log to file you will need two lines. waste of time
  and code.
- You didnt add a sample of usage therefore i dont really knwo how mant
  objects of *LogManager* you have, you shouldnt have more then one
  handling the logs.
- There is no batching of writing to the file. Dont write to file
  everytime you need to log but batch. it.
- Of course when batching the synchronization will be easier to
  accomplish.
- At this implementation when logging from UI thread you are writing to
  file, this is bad practice. Dont do any Read/Write on UI thread.

Conclusion-
You have a lot of work to do. This tips will help you creating a correct logger.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
I edited my post to show you my sample usage. I will consider your hints :)